# Good way to reduce an amount of calculations of the integration rather using greedy way .

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, systems-of-equations

$$  \left( a,b \in \mathbb R_{> 0} \right)  ~~\wedge~~ \left( a \geq b \right)  $$

$$  \int_{a-b }^{a+ b }  \frac{1}{ r^2 } \left\{ 1- \left( \frac{  a^2+b^2-r^2  }{  2ab  }  \right) ^2 \right\} \,dr   = \frac{  4b  }{  3a^2  } $$

I want to ask you any good way to integrate the above given formula of integration rather doing greedy computations .

I want to reduce an amount of calculations of the integration .

$$ A:= \int_{a-b }^{a+ b }  \frac{1}{ r^2 } \left\{ 1- \left( \frac{  a^2+b^2-r^2  }{  2ab  }  \right) ^2 \right\} \,dr   $$

$$ = \int_{a-b }^{a+b } \frac{1}{ r^2 } \left\{ 1- \frac{  \left( a^2+b^2-r^2 \right) ^2  }{  \left( 2ab \right) ^2  }  \right\}  \,dr   $$

$$ = \int_{a-b }^{a+b } \frac{1}{ r^2 } \left\{ 1- \frac{  \left( \left( a^2+b^2      \right) -r^2 \right) ^2  }{  4a^2 b^2  }  \right\}  \,dr   $$

$$ = \int_{a-b }^{a+b }  \frac{1}{ r^2 } \left\{ \frac{  4a^{2}b^{2}- \left( \left( a^2+b^2      \right) -r^2 \right) ^2 }{  4a^{2}b^{2}  }  \right\}    \,dr   $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ 4a^{2}b^{2} }  \int_{a-b }^{a+b } \frac{1}{ r^2 } \left\{ 4a^{2}b^{2}-  \left( \left( a^2+b^2      \right) -r^2 \right) ^2 \right\}    \,dr   $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ 4a^{2}b^{2} }  \int_{a-b }^{a+b } \frac{1}{ r^2 } \left\{ 4a^{2}b^{2}-  \left(\left( a^2+b^2 \right) ^2-2r^2 \left( a^2+b^2 \right) + r^4 \right)  \right\}    \,dr   $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ 4a^{2}b^{2} }  \int_{a-b }^{a+b } r^{-2} \left\{ 4a^{2}b^{2}-  \left(\left( a^2+b^2 \right) ^2-2r^2 \left( a^2+b^2 \right) + r^4 \right)  \right\}    \,dr   $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ 4a^{2}b^{2} }  \int_{a-b }^{a+b } r^{-2} \left\{  \underbrace{4a^{2}b^{2}-  \left( a^2+b^2 \right) ^2}_{=:c_{1}}  +2r^2 \left( a^2+b^2 \right) - r^4   \right\}    \,dr   $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ 4a^{2}b^{2} }  \int_{a-b }^{a+b } r^{-2} \left\{  c_{1}  +r^2 \underbrace{2\left( a^2+b^2 \right)}_{=:c_{2}}  - r^4   \right\}    \,dr   $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 } \int_{a-b }^{a+b } r^{-2} \left( c_{1}+c_{2}r^{2}-r^4 \right)  \,dr   $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 } \int_{a-b }^{a+b }  \left( c_{1}r^{-2}+c_{2}-r^2\right)  \,dr   $$

$$ = \frac{  1  }{  4 a^2 b^2  } \left\{ c_{1}  \frac{  r^{-1}  }{  \left( -1 \right)    } +c_{2} r- \frac{  r^3  }{  3  }  \right\}_{a-b}^{a+b}    $$

$$ = \frac{  1  }{  4 a^2 b^2  } \left\{ -c_{1}  \frac{ 1   }{  r    } +c_{2} r- \frac{  r^3  }{  3  }  \right\}_{a-b}^{a+b}    $$

$$ = \frac{  1  }{  4 a^2 b^2  } \left\{ -  \frac{ c_{1}   }{  r    } +c_{2} r- \frac{  r^3  }{  3  }  \right\}_{a-b}^{a+b}    $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 } \left\{  \left( -\frac{  c_{1}  }{ r   }  \right)_{a-b}^{a+b}  + c_{2} \left( r \right)_{a-b}^{a+b} - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( r^3 \right)_{a-b}^{a+b}    \right\}  $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 } \left\{  \left( \frac{  c_{1}  }{ r   }  \right)_{a+b}^{a-b}  + c_{2} \left( \left( a+b \right) - \left( a-b \right)  \right) - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( \left( a+b \right)^{3}- \left( a-b \right)^{3}   \right)    \right\}  $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 }  \left\{c_{1} \left( \frac{1}{ \left( a-b \right)  } - \frac{  1  }{  \left( a+b \right)   }  \right)     + c_{2} \left( \left( a+b \right) -  a+b   \right) - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( \left( a+b \right)^{3}- \left( a-b \right)^{3}   \right)    \right\}  $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 }  \left\{c_{1} \left( \frac{1}{ \left( a-b \right)  } - \frac{  1  }{  \left( a+b \right)   }  \right)     + c_{2}  \left( 2b   \right) - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( \left( a+b \right)^{3}- \left( a-b \right)^{3}   \right)    \right\}  $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 }  \left\{c_{1} \left(  \frac{  \left( a+b \right) -\left( a-b \right)   }{ \left( a-b \right) \left( a+b \right)    }    \right)     + 2bc_{2} - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( \left( a+b \right)^{3}- \left( a-b \right)^{3}   \right)    \right\}  $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 }  \left\{c_{1} \left(  \frac{  \left( a+b \right) - a+b   }{ \left( a-b \right) \left( a+b \right)    }    \right)     + 2bc_{2} - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( \left( a+b \right)^{3}- \left( a-b \right)^{3}   \right)    \right\}  $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 }  \left\{c_{1} \left(  \frac{  2b   }{ \left( a-b \right) \left( a+b \right)    }    \right)     + 2bc_{2} - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( \left( a+b \right)^{3}- \left( a-b \right)^{3}   \right)    \right\}  $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 }  \left\{  \frac{  2b c_{1}  }{ \left( a-b \right) \left( a+b \right)    }    + 2bc_{2} - \frac{1}{ 3 } \underbrace{\left( \left( a+b \right)^{3}- \left( a-b \right)^{3}   \right)}_{=:\text{tmp1} }     \right\} =A $$

$$  \text{tmp1}=  \left( a+b \right)^{3}- \left( a-b \right)^{3}    $$

$$ = a^3+ 3a^2b+ 3 a b ^2 + b ^ 3 - \left( a^3 -3a^2 b + 3 a b^2-b^3 \right)  $$

$$ =  a^3+ 3a^2b+ 3 a b ^2 + b ^ 3 -a^3 +3a^2 b - 3 a b^2+b^3 $$

$$ = 2 \left( 3a^2b +b^3 \right)  $$

$$ = 6 a ^2 b + 2 b^3 $$

$$  \therefore ~~ A =  \frac{1}{ 4a^2 b^2 }  \left\{  \frac{  2b c_{1}  }{ \left( a-b \right) \left( a+b \right)    }    + 2bc_{2} - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( 6a^2b+2b^3 \right)     \right\}  $$

$$  c_{1}=4a^{2}b^{2}-  \left( a^2+b^2 \right) ^2 $$

$$ = 4a^2 b^2- \left( a^4 + b^4 + 2 a^2 b^2 \right)  $$

$$ = 4a^2 b^2 -a^4 - b^4 - 2 a^2 b^2  $$

$$ =  -a^4 - b^4 + 2 a^2 b^2$$

$$ =  -\left( a^4 + b^4 - 2 a^2 b^2 \right)   $$

$$ = - \left( a^2-b^2 \right) ^2 =c_{1} $$

$$  c_{2}= 2 \left( a^2+b^2 \right)  $$

$$  A= \frac{  1  }{  4a^2 b^2  } \left\{  \frac{  2b \left( - \left( a^2-b^2 \right) ^2 \right)  }{  \left( a-b \right) \left( a+b \right)    } + 2b \left( 2 \left( a^2+b^2 \right)  \right)   - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( 6a^2b+2b^3 \right) \right\}  $$

$$  = \frac{  1  }{  4a^2 b^2  } \left\{  \frac{  -2b \left( a^2-b^2 \right) ^2   }{ \left( a^2-b^2 \right)     } + 4b  \left( a^2+b^2   \right)   - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( 6a^2b+2b^3 \right) \right\}  $$

$$  = \frac{  1  }{  4a^2 b^2  } \left\{  -2b \left( a^2-b^2 \right)     + 4b  \left( a^2+b^2   \right)   - \frac{1}{ 3 } \left( 6a^2b+2b^3 \right) \right\}  $$

$$ = \frac{  1  }{  4a^2b^2  } \left\{ -2a^2b+ 2 b^3+ 4a^2b+4b^3 -2 a^2b -\frac{  2  }{  3  } b^3  \right\} $$

$$ = \frac{  1  }{  4a^2b^2  } \left\{  b^{3 } \left( 2+4-\frac{  2  }{  3  }  \right) +a^2b \left( -2+4-2 \right)   \right\} $$

$$ = \frac{  1  }{  4a^2b^2  } \left\{  b^{3 } \left( 6-\frac{  2  }{  3  }  \right) +a^2b \cdot 0   \right\} $$

$$ = \frac{  1  }{  4a^2b^2  } \left\{  b^{3 } \left( 6-\frac{  2  }{  3  }  \right)   \right\} $$

$$ = \frac{  1  }{  4a^2b^2  } \left\{  b^{3 } \left( 6-\frac{  2  }{  3  }  \right)   \right\} $$

$$ = \frac{  b^3  }{ 4a^2 b^2   }  \left( 6-\frac{  2  }{  3  }  \right)     $$

$$ = \frac{  b  }{ 4a^2   }  \left( 6-\frac{  2  }{  3  }  \right)     $$

$$ = \frac{  2b  }{ 4a^2   }  \left( 3-\frac{  1  }{  3  }  \right)     $$

$$ = \frac{  b  }{ 2a^2   }  \left( 3-\frac{  1  }{  3  }  \right)     $$

$$ = \frac{  b  }{ 2a^2   }  \left( \frac{  9-1  }{  3  }   \right)     $$

$$ = \frac{  b  }{ 2a^2   }  \left( \frac{  8  }{  3  }   \right)     $$

$$ = \frac{  4b  }{  3a^2  }  $$

Comment: Can't you simply expand it to something of the form $\int (c_1 r^{-2} + c_2 + c_3 r^2) dr$?

Comment: I will do it . Please wait .

Comment: I think I done it .

Comment: I deduced it in my own using a greedy way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_0=\tfrac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}$ and $c_1=-\tfrac{1}{2ab}$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{a-b}^{a+b} \frac{1}{r^2}\left(\,1 - \left(\frac{a^2+b^2-r^2}{2ab}\right)^2 \,\right)\;\mathrm{d}r
&= \int_{a-b}^{a+b} \frac{1}{r^2}\left(\,1 - (c_0+c_1r^2)^2 \,\right)\;\mathrm{d}r\\
&= \int_{a-b}^{a+b} \frac{1}{r^2}\left(\,(1-c_0^2) -2c_0c_1r^2 - c_1^2r^4\,\right) \;\mathrm{d}r\\
\text{Next let $c_2=c_0^2-1$, $c_3=-2c_0c_1$, and $c_4=-c_1^2$, giving}\\
&= \int_{a-b}^{a+b} -c_2r^{-2} + c_3 + c_4r^2 \;\mathrm{d}r\\
&= c_2\left[r^{-1}\right]_{a-b}^{a+b} + c_3 \left[r\right]_{a-b}^{a+b} + \tfrac{c_4}{3} \left[r^3\right]_{a-b}^{a+b}
\end{align}

Now,
\begin{align}
\left[r^{-1}\right]_{a-b}^{a+b} &= \frac{1}{a+b} - \frac{1}{a-b} = \frac{-2b}{(a+b)(a-b)} = \frac{-2b}{a^2-b^2},\\
\left[r\right]_{a-b}^{a+b} &= (a+b)-(a-b) = -2b,\\
\left[r^3\right]_{a-b}^{a+b} &= (a+b)^3 - (a-b)^3 = 6a^2b + 2b^3
\end{align}

Resolving coefficients:
\begin{align}
c_2 &= c_0^2 - 1 = (c_0-1)(c_0+1)
= \left(\tfrac{a^2+b^2 - 2ab}{2ab}\right)\left( \tfrac{a^2+b^2+2ab}{2ab} \right)
= \frac{(a-b)^2}{2ab}\frac{(a+b)^2}{2ab} = \left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{2ab}\right)^2\\
c_3 &= -2c_0c_1 = - 2\frac{a^2+b^2}{(2ab)^2}\\
c_4 &= -c_1^2 = - \frac{1}{(2ab)^2}
\end{align}

Substituting back, we get
\begin{align}
&\int_{a-b}^{a+b} \frac{1}{r^2}\left(\,1 - \left(\frac{a^2+b^2-r^2}{2ab}\right)^2 \,\right)\;\mathrm{d}r\\
&= c_2\cdot \frac{-2b}{a^2-b^2}
+ c_3 \cdot -2b
+ \frac{c_4}{3}\cdot (6a^2b + 2b^3)\\
&= \left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{2ab}\right)^2\cdot \frac{-2b}{a^2-b^2}
+ - 2\frac{a^2+b^2}{(2ab)^2} \cdot -2b
+ \frac{1}{3} \cdot- \frac{1}{(2ab)^2}\cdot (6a^2b + 2b^3)\\
&= \frac{1}{(2ab)^2} \left(\, (a^2-b^2)(-2b)
+ 2(a^2+b^2)\cdot 2b
- \frac{1}{3}\cdot (6a^2b + 2b^3) \,\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{(2ab)^2} \cdot \frac{16}{3}b^3
= \frac{4b}{3a^2}
\end{align}